# Using CURL with oauth for desktop-couch

Tags: curl, oauth, couchdb, gnome

To access [desktopcouch](https://launchpad.net/desktopcouch) the documentation suggest to use oauth. Using the samples in the O'Reilly book "CouchDB - the definite guide" I want to use CURL (or another command line tool if appropriate) to work with desktopcouch. I guess I would need a script to query the key store to retrieve the oauth token and add it to the CURL string. Ideally I would like to create a couchurl script file that I can use instead of the CURL command for the samples in the book.
How would that script look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use twurl:
http://thechangelog.com/post/536535280/twurl-oauth-enabled-curl-for-the-twitter-api

Twurl - OAuth-enabled curl for the Twitter API
Wynn Netherland

OAuth is cool but developing with OAuth can be a pain. Inspired by curl and Hurl.it (featured on Episode 0.1.5 with Leah Culver), the Twitter team has realeased a couple of tools to make developing with the Twitter OAuth API much easier.

Twurl is a Ruby gem from Marcel Molina that lets you make requests to the Twitter OAuth API from the console. To begin install the gem:

`$ sudo gem install twurl`

Then from the command line (not the Ruby console) you can authorize twurl using your API keys:

`$ twurl authorize --consumer-key the_key  --consumer-secret the_secret`

Now you can make requests to API methods:

`$ twurl /1/statuses/home_timeline.xml`

The Twitter team also has a nifty GUI version up on the new Twitter Developers Site that even pre-populates your Twitter apps in a drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

If python is an option, it's pretty easy to implement oAuth clients using [python-oauth2](http://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2).

I tried to get OAuth working using curl but there was a lot of information passing to get it through all four steps: request_token, authorize, request_access, access. I was heading towards a fairly complicated script to do so. Certainly it was going to be more work than just using [python-oauth2](http://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2).

Answer (score 0):

There are two Python command-line tools for interacting with OAuth services a la curl:

- [curl-oauth](https://github.com/oxys-net/curl-oauth) for OAuth 1.0
- [curlish](https://github.com/fireteam/curlish) for OAuth 2.0